# What is the best form event to dynamically load a user control?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

By using LoadControl method. Is it on Page Load or on Page PreInit?

and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PreInit** – This event represents the entry point of the page life cycle. If you need to change the Master page or theme programmatically, then this would be the event to do so. Dynamic controls are created in this event.

From: [ASP.NET 2.0 Page Event Life Cycle](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=83)

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have much choice here except [LoadControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.loadcontrol.aspx)